# iFrame to move when the parent HTML page scrolls up/down, so the iframe is always in focus

Tags: html, iframe

My code is:

```
<div id="floatframe" style="left: 0px; border: 0px none; height: 70px; position: static; width: 340px; overflow: hidden; top: 0px;"> 
 <div style ="overflow: hidden;">
   <iframe src="(some src)" width="340" height="70" style="height: 300px; border: 0px none; width: 340px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 12px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="false"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to make sure the iframe is always focused, and should move down when the page scrolls down, and move up when the page scrolls up, so that the user can always see the iframe. Its position must be on the top of the page always, but as the page scrolls down, it should not lose focus on the iframe.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your iframe should be positioned on the viewport and with a positive z-index so that it is always on top.

```
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofvp4khc/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Issue i am seeing is: When I scroll down, the images on the parent page covers the iframe. Instead, I want the iframe to be visible on the top of the images. any suggestions will help.

Comment: You could possibly fix this with the z-index property, but I'm not sure what's going on with your code.  Could you post some code snippets or better yet make a jsfiddle with the relevant html and css?

Comment: Thanks again, I found the issue. Yes, z-index property worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: The z-index property doesn't necessarily have to be *positive*, as long as it's greater than *other* elements on the page. *Precedence* **may** vary. So what if there was an interfering element on the page with a greater z-index? Will not work quite right. In that case, applying an *opacity* lower than 1 will also do the trick, just so that the other element(s) on the page aren't fully covered.

Comment: @WEB_UI You probably know this, but I just thought I should mention that an element of z-index 1 & opacity 1 will not be interactable when overlayed by an element of z-index 2 & opacity 0 as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxz6Lbo0/1/)

Comment: @CraigMason Exactly, but if both `z-index` and `opacity` values are set *correspondingly,* the result is *glamorizing*, especially with the iFrame centred on other overlapping elements. However, giving it an opacity of 0 is pretty useless, unless you'd want it to be *transparent*, which you can achieve even by simply saying: `visibillity: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that easily using CSS. Simply give the iframe's container a fixed position like so:

```css
#floatFrame { position: fixed; }
```

That should help solve your problem, but you may also want to centre the iframe somewhere on the page, and give it an opacity lower than 1, so that it doesn't overlap with any other elements on the page. You can also use the `z-index` property in CSS, just in case you don't want the interfering element(s) to be visible under the iframe and the iframe to look slightly faded. But in your case, a [z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) that is **correctly set**, should do the trick.